`databricks labs ucx` dependency issues on azure cloud shell
I'm trying to install Databricks labs ucx on Azure Cloud Shell.
However, ucx requires Databricks CLI v0.213 or later. ucx also requires Python 3.10+ but only 3.9 is available on Azure Cloud Shell.
In addition Databricks CLI installer assumes sudo privilege, which isn't available on Azure Cloud Shell.
How can I work around these constraints?

This worked for me without having to sudo:
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.12.2/Python-3.12.2.tgz
tar xvzf Python-3.12.2.tgz 
cd Python-3.12.2
./configure --with-pydebug
make
cd ..
export PATH=./Python-3.12.2:$PATH

wget https://github.com/databricks/cli/releases/download/v0.216.0/databricks_cli_0.216.0_linux_amd64.zip
unzip databricks_cli_0.216.0_linux_amd64.zip 
./databricks configure
# enter workspace url, username and PAT/password

./databricks labs install ucx

